# Windows 8 won't run two NVIDIA cards simultaneously

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I had a NVIDIA GeForce 6500 graphics card that was working great (I had one screen using the DVI and one using the S-Video), I just installed a new NVIDIA GeForce G210. The new card seems to work but I can't get anything from the old one now, it just sort of flickers, and when I try to do an extended desktop from one of the screens on the new card to a screen on the old everything goes black and windows restarts... Any ideas?

Comment: Verify you can mix and match NVIDIA cards like that.  Its my understand that you can only connect two different NVIDIA cards if they are the same or similar model.

Comment: How could I verify that? That's where I started and I wasn't able to get a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the fact that these two cards do not use the same chip-set they will not run together. Sorry but you will have to choose one or the other. In order to run in SLI they must meet these requirements.

https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/469402/sli/faq-quot-will-these-two-cards-work-in-sli-quot-sli-what-works-with-what-/

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! I took your advice.. the G210 won.

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa. It's true that they cannot run in SLI, but they certainly CAN operate separately, powering different displays. I have personally accomplished this with a GTX 580 and 9800GT. From the description of what happens from @Blake it looks like more of a hardware malfunction (power supply, motherboard) to me.

Comment: @ChrisStauffer Clearly they aren't playing nicely.